# Hash table instantly becomes empty while server still running

Tags: c, hashtable

I have a small TCP connection where I am trying to send a char array that I pull out of a hash table. I can successfully add a string to the hash table with a key being the client's IP address, but when I try to get the values for the key it registers the entire table as NULL.

Here's the file:

```
void HandleTCPClient(int clntSocket, char *client_ip, HASHTBL *hashtable)
{
    ...
    ...
    if (strcmp(cmd, "addfile") == 0)
    {
        char arr[1000];
        add = hashtbl_get(hashtable, (char *)client_ip);

        if (add != NULL)
        {
            memcpy(fls, add, strlen(add));
            hashtbl_insert(hashtable, client_ip, fls);
        }
        else
        {
            hashtbl_insert(hashtable, client_ip, fls);
            printf("insert done\n");
        }
        printf("%s\n", hashtbl_get(hashtable, (char *)client_ip));
    }

    else if (strcmp(cmd, "listfiles") == 0)
    {
        char list[1000];
        char *test;

        printf("before getting from hashtable");

        test = hashtbl_get(hashtable, (char *)client_ip);

        printf("%s\n", test);
    }
```

The function I'm calling to get the value, `hashtbl_get` has the header:

```
void *hashtbl_get(HASHTBL *hashtbl, const char *key);
```

and so I cast the client_ip as a `(char *)` when I pass it in.

`fls` is a small char array

The `hashtbl_get` function is here:

```
void *hashtbl_get(HASHTBL *hashtbl, const char *key)
{
struct hashnode_s *node;
hash_size hash=hashtbl->hashfunc(key)%hashtbl->size;

node=hashtbl->nodes[hash];
while(node) {
    if(!strcmp(node->key, key)) return node->data;
    node=node->next;
}

return NULL;
}
```

The problem is that, when I run my server and call the `addfile` command it adds to the hash table, but when I call `listfiles` it acts as though the hash table is now empty. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: It seems quite possible it is a bug in either hashtbl_insert or hashtbl_get.  It seems there is not enough information here to determine the problem (e.g., what is `fls` and how does it get filled for the else?)

Comment: I'm pretty confident that hashtbl_insert is okay because in my print statement right below I was able to retrieve the value using the `hashtbl_get` function. It just doesn't cooperate when I use it again in the "listfiles" command. I edited my post, but `fls` is just a char array.

Comment: `memcpy(fls, add, strlen(add));` Are you sure you don't want to copy the 0-terminator there?

Comment: I'll just add it to the end later. For the moment that part of the condition is never met because the hash table is empty.

Comment: How is `hashtable` maintained between calls?  Is it a global variable?  Is it maybe a local variable in some function that goes out of scope between requests?

Comment: Well right now the hash table is created and then passed into the function I posted above. It is technically global, and in between my calls to insert and then get nothing is happening to the hash table.

Comment: @febreezey:  Hmmm.  Based on the available information, it "seems" like it should work (contrary to actual behavior :)  The simplest thing would be to set a breakpoint in the `listfiles` portion of the code and step through it in a debugger.  If you are stuck with printf style debugging, I would just print out the entire contents of the hash table at that point (and the given client_ip value) to make sure it all looks normal.